# Python Flask calling different version API

Tags: python, api, flask, versioning

I'm new to Python Flask, I'm having an issue with versioning API design. Consider the URL to perform the GET method to the user API.

```
v1 - <URL>/api/v1/users?q=getUserInfo?name=ryan
v2 - <URL>/api/v2/users?q=getUserInfo?name=ryan&gender=male
```

While 'user' API in v1 and v2 might have a different implementation in the development period, the client will call a different version of API for different requests and API responds differently according to API call. How should I route the client to the respective version of the API while the user calls the different API?

Here is my server.py:

```py
from flask import Flask, request
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '../api')
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api/<version>/<api>/<action>')
def api(version, api, action):
    # How should I call my API and get return data to the client?
    return json.dumps(return_info)  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='127.0.0.1', port='8081')
```

In my api/v1/user.py

```py
def getUserInfo(name):
    # some logic and return user info
```

In my api/v2/user.py

```py
def getUserInfo(name, gender):
    # some logic and return user info
```

The basic idea is the server.py act as the central route to a different version of API based on the client's request and response to the client.

Besides, API in different version contains multiple `.py` files for modular design, for example: `<version>/product.py` API handles request for product, `<version>/cart.py` API handles request for cart, etc.

So the question is, how should I call to my different version of API file and return the response to the client?

Comment: if its still relevant I wrote a package to manage endpoints by versions You can find it on Git https://github.com/itay-bardugo/flask_version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note, its not obligatory to have versioning for all resources.
 When we support a different versions of endpoints within a single server node (or microservice) - we are usually call them *"coexisting endpoints"*.
If you decide to pass an API version as dynamic request param `<version>` you have to implement a custom dispatcher to load/apply a different handler for each version.
A much easier way to support coexisting endpoints is to register different routes for each version.
While [Sanic](https://sanic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sanic/getting_started.html) server allows to pass the [version](https://sanic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sanic/versioning.html#versioning) keyword to the route decorators, or to a blueprint initializer, in Flask you could apply simple [blueprints](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/master/tutorial/views/):

```
...
# import <needed_features> from api/v1/user.py
# import <needed_features> from api/v2/user.py
...

bp_api_v1 = Blueprint('api_v1', __name__, url_prefix='/api/v1')
bp_api_v2 = Blueprint('api_v2', __name__, url_prefix='/api/v2')

app.register_blueprint(bp_api_v1)
app.register_blueprint(bp_api_v2)

@bp_api_v1.route('/users/<action>')
def api(request, action):
    # call getUserInfo from api/v1/user.py
    user_info = getUserInfo(request.args.get('name'))
    return json.dumps(user_info)    


@bp_api_v2.route('/users/<action>')
def api(request, action):
    # call getUserInfo from api/v2/user.py
    user_info = getUserInfo(request.args.get('name'))
    return json.dumps(user_info)
```